# Design pattern for bi directional data format conversion

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, data-conversion

I work on a project that will deal with different data formats.

for example, suppose i have the following data formats:

```
formatA, formatB, formatC, ...
```

with the following classes.

**formatA**:

```
public class dataFormatA {

    private String data;

    public dataFormatA(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        // convertData(this.data);
    }

    public dataFormatB convertToDataFormatB() {
        return new dataFormatB(data);
    }

    public dataFormatC convertToDataFormatC() {
        return new dataFormatC(data);
    }

}
```

**formatB**:

```
public class dataFormatB {

    private String data;

    public dataFormatB(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        // convertData(this.data);
    }

    public dataFormatA convertToDataFormatA() {
        return new dataFormatA(data);
    }

    public dataFormatC convertToDataFormatC() {
        return new dataFormatC(data);
    }

}
```

**formatC**:

```
public class dataFormatC {

    private String data;

    public dataFormatC(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        // convertData(this.data);
    }

    public dataFormatA convertToDataFormatA() {
        return new dataFormatA(data);
    }

    public dataFormatB convertToDataFormatB() {
        return new dataFormatB(data);
    }
}
```

What is the best design pattern to make? currently, each class has a method to convert its data type to the rest of data formats classes. But this is not a good design as it violat the **open close principle**

Comment: What about a common interface (`interface DataContainer { String getData(); }` that all implement? That would either remove the need to convert or allow a constructor of like `public dataFormatC(DataContainer other)`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you devise one (or a very small number of) intermediate format(s)? Let's call such a format `M`; then you'll only need converters from each format to `M`, and from `M` to each format. Adding more formats becomes easy.

If you have a nontrivial and unique way of conversion between each pair of formats, you're stuck with having a full matrix.

You still don't need to keep the converters code inside the format class.

Instead, I'd create a common converter interface:

```
interface FormatConverter<SRC, DST> {
   DST convertFrom(SRC);
}
```

Now you can use any mechanism you like to implement this interface, likely by having a bunch of converter classes.

The converters may see certain non-public details of each format class via package-level visibility. Alternatively, they could be format's inner classes. OTOH this again creates a tight coupling between the format class and converters, so open-closed principle may be violated.

Comment: How could you dynamically convert data formats while remaining type-safe? It seems the only way to lookup the proper converter would be to use reflection or a service locator, no? Therefore, the compiler couldn't detect missing conversions.

Comment: So, if i have 4 data format classes, i need to create a 12 class combination for converting from type to another?